# Find differences between two columns in different dataframes pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (df1, df2) both containing column 'A'. Lenght of df1['A'] is 678, while lenght of df2['A'] is 618. I want to compare those two columns from both dataframes and print out values (60), that only appeared in df1 and not df2, so i can detect which values differ in dataframe's columns.

```
df1                   df2

 A B C D E...         A B C D E...
 1                    3
 2                    4
 3                    5
 4
 5

Result woud be: (1,2)
```

So far i tried:

```
set(df1['A']).intersection(set(df2['A']))
```

Which returns me duplicates.

```
df1[~df1.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1))]
```

Which returns me total a total mess of 678 row with messed order cells.

Comment: Use `df1[~df1.A.isin(df2.A)]`

Comment: @jezrael I think better `pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)` as it seems he will have multiple columns

Comment: @Datanovice - Yop, but title says comparing by 2 columns.